# How can I use version 2.0 of PHPSeclib to get a signed string as I did in version 1.0?

Tags: php, rsa, phpseclib, encryption-asymmetric

There is one project I worked on where a teammate added [phpseclib (for php5)](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib-php5/tree/master/phpseclib) and we use the code below to sign an encrypted string and send that with a request to an internal API for verification processes.

```
function GetSignature($message) {
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $sPath = PRIVATE_KEY_FILE; //defined elsewhere
    $sKey = file_get_contents($sPath);
    $rsa->LoadKey($sKey);
    $rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
    return $rsa->sign($message);
};
```

For a string that contains a timestamp concatenated with a URL (e.g. *1490239371+[https://api-domain/api/endpoint](https://api-domain/api/endpoint_)*), that would generate a string like below. This string is sent in a request header and the string below is the output in the internal API's console log.

> *Rsh1dv5ZGaPjCb6pgEsMrXwZbAeVgxVK/+5d5bxu7BfDzaILl++/pi/WxDP4H2qJ7Ayp6QnYXGckIIYX9l9fKOJoShOZOkB19RxaNdBL5vLjKk409XVRY/GKGz3kHmZmTcyBYDPQaT/VFOQTd7+o0d1mBY4EbHadI3f+kahHz4U=*

In a newer project, I am attempting to recreate this because we need to utilize the same internal API. The newer project is utilizing composer (and laravel) so adding phpseclib to it added [version 2.0](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/2.0). The constants have been changed to class constants but other than that it appears the methods are identical. Below is the code I added to replicate the former code in the other codebase.

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA as Crypt_RSA;
class EncyptionController {

    public static function GetSignature($message) {
        $rsa = new Crypt_RSA(); 
        $path = config('app.encryption_key_path') . '/certs/private.pem';
        $rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents($path));
        $rsa->setSignatureMode(Crypt_RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
        return $rsa->sign($message); 
    }
```

With the newer code, a string of the same format would yield an encrypted string that contains unicode characters. The string below appears in the internal API's console log (when logging the value received in the request headers).

> =���˭\u0003�uʂ\u000e_\u0013\u000bd)w�8�\u0018�����q

Logging that in Laravels log shows it with the unicode characters (without the entities encoded - I opened it in [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)):

> =žšîË­´uÊ‚_d)wË8ƒ”ñ‘¤úqýÁ‹þ:‹dºäÿLÈ?!F§?…ãIEìê*K®gUþèÎÅ

And then the internal API decrypts the encoded string using the public key. For the newer codebase this fails. The internal API is implemented in Nginx/NodeJS and uses [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) and its [verifier.verify()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_verifier_verify_object_signature_signature_format) method.

#### Update:

Based on [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966964/how-can-i-use-version-2-0-of-phpseclib-to-get-a-signed-string-as-i-did-in-versio#comment-73056109) by [Álvaro González](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%C3%81lvaro-gonz%C3%A1lez), it has come to light that the version 2.0 *sign()* method returns a raw binary hash. I can use [base64_encode()](http://php.net/base64_encode) to base-64 encode it, but the string is quite a bit shorter (88 characters) than the strings produced by version 1.0 (172 characters).

```
return base64_encode($rsa->sign($message));
```

version 1.0 string - 172 characters long:

> Rsh1dv5ZGaPjCb6pgEsMrXwZbAeVgxVK/+5d5bxu7BfDzaILl++/pi/WxDP4H2qJ7Ayp6QnYXGckIIYX9l9fKOJoShOZOkB19RxaNdBL5vLjKk409XVRY/GKGz3kHmZmTcyBYDPQaT/VFOQTd7+o0d1mBY4EbHadI3f+kahHz4U='
>   "Rsh1dv5ZGaPjCb6pgEsMrXwZbAeVgxVK/+5d5bxu7BfDzaILl++/pi/WxDP4H2qJ7Ayp6QnYXGckIIYX9l9fKOJoShOZOkB19RxaNdBL5vLjKk409XVRY/GKGz3kHmZmTcyBYDPQaT/VFOQTd7+o0d1mBY4EbHadI3f+kahHz4U=

version 2.0 string - 88 characters long:

> mYT/MSb9UOuDDQ1RV893Ix7xh21IRHINs6o1PnhdhffgTAIeX4le1rfd+EzoPPJN9pvvwirm3CAbkeubGjXgWQ==

Is there a method to set the length of the signed string?

Comment: How exactly are you printing this? Do you see the same issue when you write the output to a file and open it in a "good" editor?

Comment: Good question @ArtjomB. I updated the post to contain that info. The original strings were written to nginx's log via _console.log()_. I included the output in the new codebase to laravel's log (and opening the log in notepad++).

Comment: @SamOnela This has nothing to do with Unicode (the whole purpose of Unicode is to handle text, and this is clearly binary data). In v1 you were getting a hash encoded as base64. In v2 you're getting a raw binary hash. As they warn, v2 API is not final and may change any time until v3. You should start by comparing both hashes to see if they are identical.

Comment: Thanks @Álvaro González for pointing that out. I updated the question to deal with varying string lengths after manually base-64 encoding the raw hash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v2.0 it's RSA() - not Crypt_RSA(). http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/2.0.html elaborates.

Anyway, in base64 decoding your two ciphertext's and then getting the length of each...  the first one (the one produced by phpseclib-php5) I get 256 bytes or 2048 bits. The second one (the one produced by phpseclib 2.0) is 64 bytes of 512 bits.

I think you're using different keys of different lengths for each one and that'd definitely affect the length.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I used a [namespace alias](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) for _RSA_ `as Crypt_RSA` in an attempt to make it a closer match to the existing code. I updated my post for that. I checked the keys and tried using the same key files as in the older project. I also realized I was not formulating the message in the same fashion (i.e. not casting a timestamp as a string, and appending an extra part of the request path). Now It is working as expected. Thanks for the guidance!